# Listen to Usabilla window close event in angular app

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm using [Usabilla](https://usabilla.com/) for feedback, and I need to add logic on close event of the feedback modal. What is the best way to do this inside of Angular app?

Usabilla is not important here. You may assume it's just a modal window inside iframe, with obfuscated source code. Important is to catch the moment when user closes the dialog - whether by click on close button, submit button, or click on the backdrop.